# Entity Framework 4.1 : How to do sub query in Select

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1, subquery

I am trying to do following using `Entity Framework 4.1` Code First:

```
Select c1,
       c2,
       (select v1 from table2 where id = c3) as col3
from table1
```

Any help is really appreciated.

**EDIT:**

For example, let's say I have two tables in database,

*LookupValues [ ID, Code, DescResourceID ]*

*Resources [ResourceID, Culture, Value ]*

DescResourceID and ResourceID are Foreign Keys.

So I want to create a Configuration or mapping for...

```
public partial class LookupValues
{
  public virtual string ID;
  public virtual string Code;
  public virtual string Description;
}
```

Description is mapped to `subquery` as mentioned above.

Comment: Your question would be really easier to answer if your code wouldn't be so "pseudo" and out of any context. Do you already have an EF Code-First model and did you try something? Can you show that with a more concrete example?

Comment: Yes I do have code first model. I mentioned above  for simplicity purpose. Basically I am looking to create mapping for above mentioned scenario. Or other possible workarounds. The way I have currently is table2 as child of table1. Problem with that is, it loads all rows from table2 for each row of table1, whereas I want only one value of table2 for each row or table1. Let me know if that make sense, or else I will try to put actual code in here. I guess that would be little confusing. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
var query = from x in context.Table1 
            let z = context.Table2
                           .Where(y => y.Id == c3)
                           .Select(y => y.V1).FirstOrDefault()
            select new
                {
                    C1 = x.C1,
                    C2 = x.C2,
                    C3 = z
                };
```

Comment: Is there anyway we can create mapping file? For example, say table2 is resource table in database for localization. table1 has resourceId which gets fetched from table2 when above scenario is mapped to an object. So instead of making two round trips it maps correct values to the object.

Comment: There are some limited possibilities when using EDMX for mapping like [DefiningQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738450.aspx) or [QueryView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716798.aspx) (= working with EDMX without designer) but I'm not sure if it achieves exactly what you want. Also result of these advanced mapping techniques is read-only.

Comment: Yeah DefinedQuery could be one possible way but we are EF 4.1 using Code First approach which doesn't support that feature. Please see edited original post. Thanks.

Comment: In such case you must use database view. Code first is not suitable for advanced mapping scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an Entity Model and use LINQ.

I assume you know what LINQ is as you're working with Entity Framework.

Let's assume you have a data structure like the following;

Products and products has (Column1, Column2, Column3)
Categories and Categories key has a Column3 which is equivilant to the Products.Column3

Do the following;

```
var categories_Column3 = List<Categories>().Select(c => c.Column3 == some value);
var products_Column3_Query = List<Products>().Select(c => c.Column3 == categories_Column3).ToList<value_type_of_column3>();
```

Of course, this is just some psuedo code, and because I want to make sure you get the hang of LINQ and realize you can do what you want in LINQ using Entity Framework as it's OR/M I will now point you to the following site, which should give you a thorough tutorial on LINQ.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx

Hope this helps!

Happy Coding! ;)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Yes I am familiar with LINQ. But above above line of code doesn't exactly do what I am looking for. Either I can create a join and have categories as child of products, but in that case I am fetching all categories values instead of one. I want to fetch just that one value from table2 based on value in respective row from table1. Also, I am using entity framework 4.1 code first approach.